# How would you make a script to take out information from a list of string, and reinsert it into another list of strings?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to write a script that takes a list of strings, takes out certain information from that list, and re-inserts it into a different formatted string

Example:

"Hello, I am NAME1, I am from LOCATION, and I am GENDER"

to

"Hello, I'm from LOCATION, Im GENDER, my name is NAME1"
(Taking information from a set position and reinputting it into a different position)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

```py
given = "Hello, I am NAME1, I am from LOCATION, and I am GENDER"
data = given.replace("and", "").split(", ")
output = f"{data[0]}, {data[2]}, {data[3]}, and {data[1]}"
print(output)
```

```
>> Hello, I am from LOCATION,  I am GENDER, and I am NAME1
```